# less-rails doesn't generate digest assets with assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rake, asset-pipeline, sprockets, less-rails

I am building a gem and have some assets in namespace under the less, fonts and the images folder. In each of the less files wherever there is a `url('')` for font or image, I am using `asset-url('')` with the same contents.
After that when I run `rake assets:precompile RAILS-ENV=production` the rest of the urls which doesn't belong to this gem are appended with digests, but my gem just appends /assets to the url. Works fine in development but not in production.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. 
The asset name started with a "/". No wonder it was ignored assuming its the real path. Works great without the leading slash.